# Update records in table based on hours difference between dates

Tags: oracle

I am trying to update records in tables which are more than 24 hours old (1 day). I thought of taking difference on Day instead of hours by using below query :

```
UPDATE Testing 
SET STS_CD='02'
WHERE EXTRACT(DAY FROM SYSTIMESTAMP)- EXTRACT(DAY FROM UPD_DTM)> 1
```

Now, there could be situation where we have to check records which are 12 hours old or 36 hours old. So, I have to take difference based on Hours only now.
And, I am not getting correct result when trying to get difference on the based of hours. Can you please suggest ?

```
UPDATE Testing 
SET STS_CD='02'
WHERE EXTRACT(HOURS FROM SYSTIMESTAMP)- EXTRACT(HOURS FROM UPD_DTM)> 24
```

Comment: first you should change AND to WHERE , otherwise you get syntax error. Can you plz identify the UPD_DTM calumn type? DATE or TIMESTAMP?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Column `UPD_DTM` seems to be a `TIMESTAMP` value, in this case I would recommend

```
UPDATE Testing 
SET STS_CD='02'
WHERE SYSTIMESTAMP - UPD_DTM > INTERVAL '1' DAY
```

If you need the difference in hours you can also use

```
WHERE SYSTIMESTAMP - UPD_DTM > INTERVAL '24' HOUR
```

When you use `EXTRACT(HOURS FROM ...)` then you get just the hour value.

For example `EXTRACT(HOUR FROM TIMESTAMP '2018-09-24 15:00:00')- EXTRACT(HOUR FROM TIMESTAMP '2018-09-22 14:00:00')` the result is just **1** (hour), in fact the difference is 49 hours, i.e. 2 days and 1 hour (`+02 01:00:00.000000`)

You have similar problem with `EXTRACT(DAY FROM SYSTIMESTAMP)- EXTRACT(DAY FROM UPD_DTM)`, for example `EXTRACT(DAY FROM TIMESTAMP '2018-09-22 15:00:00')- EXTRACT(DAY FROM TIMESTAMP '2018-08-22 14:00:00')` returns 0, although having a difference of one month!

In case you have an index on column `UPD_DTM` then for best performance you should prefer

```
WHERE UPD_DTM < SYSTIMESTAMP - INTERVAL '1' DAY
```

Answer (score 0):

Date arithmetic works with number of days, unless you want something different. For example, if you subtract your date column and number 2 (`upd_dtm - 2`), you'll get "two days ago".

Updating rows whose date column is within the last 1 day (or 24 hours) would then be

```
UPDATE Testing 
SET STS_CD = '02'
WHERE upd_dtm > sysdate - 1
```

Or, `where upd_dtm > sysdate - 24/24` (as one day has 24 hours).

Have a look at this as well; might help you in the future:

```
SQL> alter session set nls_date_format = 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi';

Session altered.

SQL> select
  2    sysdate - 1 one_day_ago,
  3    sysdate - 12/24 twelve_hours_ago,
  4    sysdate - 36/24 thirty_six_hours_ago
  5  from dual;

ONE_DAY_AGO      TWELVE_HOURS_AGO THIRTY_SIX_HOURS
---------------- ---------------- ----------------
23.09.2018 09:38 23.09.2018 21:38 22.09.2018 21:38

SQL>
```

Comment: `SYSTIMESTAMP` is a `TIMESTAMP` value and `upd_dtm` seems to be as well a `TIMESTAMP` rather than a `DATE`. The difference of two `TIMESTAMP` values is an `INTERVAL`, see [Datetime/Interval Arithmetic](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/sql_elements001.htm#SQLRF00208)

Comment: @Wernfried, you're right. However, I don't think that the OP specified UPD_DTM column's datatype (WHERE clause talks about "systimestamp", but - why? Maybe it shouldn't. Don't know.). "1 day" (or "24 hours") lasts exactly the same, regardless DATE or TIMESTAMP (at least, I hope so! :)).  I based my code on DATE, as you've already noticed. If it turns out to be a TIMESTAMP, then yes - interval would be used.

Comment: OP wrote originally *"UPD_DTM format : 01-JAN-53 12.00.00.000000000"* - which is basically wrong but implies that datatype of `UPD_DTM` is `TIMESTAMP`, otherwise you don't have fractional seconds.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I can't see that anywhere on this page (apart from your comment, above), @Wernfried.

Answer (score 0):

if UPD_DTM column type is timestamp :

```
UPDATE Testing  
SET STS_CD='02' 
WHERE  extract (day from (systimestamp -UPD_DTM )) >1;
```

if UPD_DTM column type is date:

```
UPDATE Testing 
SET STS_CD='02'
WHERE  sysdate-UPD_DTM >1;
```

Comment: Your first query will raise an `ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected INTERVAL DAY TO SECOND got NUMBER`,. see [Datetime/Interval Arithmetic](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/sql_elements001.htm#SQLRF00208)

Comment: No, it would be the same exception

Comment: Still pointless. `extract (day from ...)` returns number of days as integer value, so you don't have any hour resolution. `x *24*60*60*1000 > 1 *24*60*60*1000` is also pointless, i.e. the same as `x > 1`

Comment: for confirmation I checked this : select systimestamp,systimestamp -1 , systimestamp-(systimestamp -1) ,  extract (day from (systimestamp - (systimestamp-1))) from dual

Comment: Operation `-1` is a `NUMBER`, not a `TIMESTAMP`. Try `SYSTIMESTAMP - TIMESTAMP '2018-09-24 15:00:00'` then you will see the difference - or read the referred document.

Comment: It doesn't make sense, systimestamp-1 returns a DATE!  TIMESTAMP '2018-09-24 10:00:00' - 1 also returns a DATE!

Comment: Yes but `systimestamp -UPD_DTM` returns an `INTERVAL` (as UPD_DTM seems to be also a `TIMESTAMP`)

Comment: Then  extract (day from ( systimestamp  - UPD_DTM )) works fine!

Comment: Yes, provided that the difference shall be based on days, however the question is "... based on **hours** difference"